# USB host power dc/dc converter chip

Tags: power-supply, usb, dc-dc-converter, usb-host, wall-wart

I'm looking for a (cheap, surface mount) single-chip dc/dc converter to power a USB connection. I'm thinking that with so many USB chargers available, there might be a chip available **specifically targeted** at just that market. So far I haven't found any, because I'm swamped with retail devices and battery charge controller chips which run FROM USB. **I want to run USB from a battery**. For the purposes of this question, the battery will be a 3.7v LiPo.

Does anyone know such a chip? I know I can get 5V dc/dc power converters, I'm looking to see if I can do better by finding one **specifically targeted** at usb host application.

While USB loads can vary, it should at least handle the typical standard USB-host load current of 500mA.

Comment: What is your input voltage, output current, efficiency target?

Comment: You will probably need an inductor, a couple of capacitors and a couple of resistors as well. Without knowledge of battery and load current this question might as well be "can you help me find a thing".

Comment: You can get single chip boost ics which only need one or two caps at most, but those normally have <250mA supply capacity. If you are only finding retail devices and battery charge chips, I'm guessing you haven't been looking at ic manufacturer websites?

Comment: You don't have enough information for anyone to formulate an answer. Do you need a buck converter? A boost converter? Buck-Boost/SEPIC? The fact that you seem to have edited your post without actually adding information, and are being a dick, results in a downvote.

Comment: Basically, the **absolute minimum** needed information for an answer is the **input** voltage range you're hoping to work with (we know the output voltage, because it's USB).

Comment: "*When you can point to even one such device, then you can criticize the question for not being specific enough.*" No. That isn't how it works. Just because something may not exist isn't good enough reason to post vague hand-waving questions which display an utter lack of clarity on what actually needs to be accomplished and how.

Comment: Those of you who don't know an answer to the specific question are not adding any value by requesting a different question.

Comment: @david the problem is that when people are asking for more specifics, its not always simply for your benefit. It's for them to be able to help you, but also, for others users who might find your question in the future. For example, I just assumed you were using a single LIPO or similar battery that runs under 5v, so a boost converter would be needed. You could have been using 4 NiMH and needed a buck/boost instead. Or you could have been using two lipo in series for 7.4v, so a buck converter would be needed. That's why people asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search found TI has an line of USB Switches with integrated Boost Converters (one with an added 3.3v LDO out as well)

http://www.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=analog&familyId=3189&uiTemplateId=NODE_STRY_PGE_T&paramCriteria=no

The TPS2500 and TPS2501 are the same except for a power save mode on the 2500. 1.8v to 5v input, regulated 5v out with selectable current limiting. Current output up to 1.4A on a single current limited output.

The TSP2505 has two individually limited outputs, an aux 5v out, a 3.3v ldo, and can source up to 2.3A between the aux and usb outputs.

Comment: I've just come off 4 hours out of my second day of searching for information like this. Including more than 1 hour on the TI site. Fortunately, I see that I was correct in judging that somebody here would be able to come up with an easy answer with minimal effort. I'm not sure if bragging about how little effort it took you was intended as an insult: I'll take it just that you got off subject a little bit while writing your answer.

Comment: @david I don't think it was bragging. Also, if it wasn't meant as an insult, I would offer to make it one: Bragging about how you were unable to obtain results in 4 hours of searching using the same search tools others would, begs an insult, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: And this is what people come to expect here: you ask a question you don't know the answer to, in the hope and expectation that someone else will already know the answer, and a lot of people who don't know the answer tell you it's a bad question because it doesn't have an answer (!). It's not me you've insulted: it's them.

Comment: @david, no you were right. It was a bit snippy on my part, which is why I edited it out. The question is good, just needed some information to make it better.